# JS. while loop crashes tab

Tags: javascript, loops

I'll go crazy. I am writing code that cyclically gets data from the server and if I use a while loop:

```
var i = 100;

while (200>i) {         
    zz.api("get", {"offset": i, "v": 5.14}, function(data) { 
        ids = ids.concat(data.response.items.map(maps));
        i= i + 100;
        alert(ids.length);
    });
}
```

In chrome Tab stops responding, Firefox crashes.

If I use for loop

```
var i = 100;

for (i=100; i<200; i= i+100) {          
    zz.api("get", {"offset": i, "v": 5.14}, function(data) { 
        ids = ids.concat(data.response.items.map(maps));
        alert(ids.length);
    });
}
```

The script is executed correctly.

WHAT am I doing wrong? 
I can not understand, why browser dies from "while" looping.

Comment: "stops responding" the key phrase. It "crashes" because you *block the UI "thread"* (i.e. the condition doesn't end when you think it should)

Comment: I don't know why `zz.api` is, but I'm sure it's asynchronous. So your `i = i + 100` probably doesn't get fired immediately, allowing the loop to continue iterating many more times quickly, blocking the asynchronous thing to run...thus crashing the browser.

Comment: Sticking functions that have callbacks inside while loops, and updating the iterator inside the callback is never a good idea, stick with the for loop.

Comment: Why, then, alternatively there is no problem? Yes, the request is asynchronous. It is necessary to sort out a lot of information and make a large number of requests cycle, as in this case it is better to do?

Comment: @user3356784 Because your `for` loop increments `i` at the end of each iteration - your `while` loop doesn't. Look at the posted answer - it's closer to what the `for` loop does. Your original `while` loop only increments `i` when the callback is executed. The `while` loop is blocking that from happening anyways. Your `for` loop doesn't increment inside the callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same result as `for` can be done with

```
var i = 100;

while (200>i) {         
    zz.api("get", {"offset": i, "v": 5.14}, function(data) { 
        ids = ids.concat(data.response.items.map(maps));
        alert(ids.length);
    });
    i= i + 100;
}
```

In the other case, `while` keeps executing infinitely until `async` call is finished and callback is called, but as this loop goes infinite callback will never get called in javascripts single threaded execution and i never gets incremented. Meanwhile infinite number of `zz.api` is called resulting in many ajax calls which helps in even easier crashing.

Comment: ok, i understand u) Thanks, I do not know why I decided to put out the increment

Answer (score 0):

You guys are forgetting the "Break" tag, it ends the loop. Without it, it crashes. You could do a do while loop too, those work nice.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34004502)